# how to get value on other table in trigger on oracle

Tags: oracle

```
declare
tgl RENC_DITSEK.TGL_INPUT%TYPE;
thn varchar(10) := :new.tahun + 1;
target RENC_DITSEK.TARGET_2%TYPE;
BEGIN

select TARGET_2 into target from RENC_DITSEK where KODE_RENCANA = :NEW.KODE_RENCANA;

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO tgl FROM DUAL;
IF UPDATING ('TARGET_2') THEN
INSERT INTO NOTE_LOG VALUES(:NEW.PKP,'',:NEW.INDIKATOR,'Target Tahun '||thn,'',:new.target_2,**target**,tgl,'','0');
    END IF;
END;
```

hi, there is my trigger body. i need a value of TARGET_2 before it updated, but i have no ide to do that. so this is my code, but it error "mutating table". is there a way to do that? please help.
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would help if you provide the table and the trigger definitions.
  e.g. what table are you creating the trigger on? Is KODE_RENCANA the primary key of the table?

If the answer to the above questions is Yes, then you don't need to execute a SELECT statement, since you could get the value of TARGET_2 using :OLD.TARGET_2 for the record you're updating.

If KODE_RENCANA is not the primary key, and it is actually a field that could be updated, and you want to retrieve another record in the same table given the new KODE_RENCANA value, then the problem is more complicated, which I would not recommend using a trigger to handle, instead, try creating a stored procedure and call the stored procedure to perform the update.

cheers.